# Excel VBA - Check combolist values and add if not already added

Tags: vba, excel

Little unsure how to phrase my question - So I apologize if it seems a little ambiguous. I have seem other methods around for things like, checking multiple combo boxes etc, but nothing that relates specifically to what I'm looking for, unsure if maybe I'm trying to do something that's just not possible.

What I want to do is check my combo box to see if a value is already present and if not and add it.

Workbook opens and calls UserForm1.show - this triggers the Userform initialize which sets some text box defaults (empty and sets things like autosize etc.) this works great, during this process I call a personal function DrpDwn_init - the idea is that DrpDwn_init with check and set values in the combo box. I can get the function to call, I can even get it to add values, but I cannot figure out how to check if a value is already present.

What I have at the moment is the following:

```
Public Function DrpDwn_Init()

Dim Templates() As String
Templates = Split("Stuff 1*Stuff 2", "*")

For i = 0 To UBound(Templates)
If Templates(i) <> UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.List(i) Then
    MsgBox "Does Not match"
Else
    MsgBox "Does Match"
End If
Next i

End Function
```

also attempted using

```
For i = 0 To UBound(Templates)
If CStr(Templates(i)) <> UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.List(i) Then

For i = 0 To UBound(Templates)
If Templates(i) <> CStr(UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.List(i)) Then

For i = 0 To UBound(Templates)
If CStr(Templates(i)) <> CStr(UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.List(i)) Then
```

as well as using the "UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.ListIndex(i)

I have tried SO many ways around this, sometimes the only error I get is that, all of a sudden Userform1.show becomes unacceptable!? even though I never touch this part of the code. I really cannot figure out how to loop through the array, check each array index item to see if it is present in the combo box or not and perform tasks based on whether it is or isn't.

Really hoping someone round here can assist me with figuring this out
(BTW. I have checked all my code references to functions etc are right, if I have made typos here I apologise.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't looping through all of the items in your dropdown box each time. Consider the following example

**List 1**

```
Apples
Pears
```

**List 2**

```
Oranges
Apples
```

The checks you need to do are the following:

```
Apples = Oranges (FALSE)
Apples = Apples (TRUE)
Pears = Oranges (FALSE)
Pears = Apples (FALSE)
```

So the simple loop here is something like

```
For i = 1 to 2
    For j = 1 to 2
        if list1(i) = list2(j) then
            inList = TRUE
        End if
    Next j
    If inList = TRUE then
        MsgBox "Found in the list"
    End if
Next i
```

**UPDATED** The code below should work with a single userform and a combobox on that userform (UserForm1 and ComboBox1, respectively)

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim inList As Boolean
Dim vListItems As Variant, vTestItems As Variant, vItem As Variant

vListItems = Array("Apple", "Orange")
vTestItems = Array("Pear", "Apple")

'populate ComboBox1
For Each vItem In vListItems
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem vItem
Next vItem

For i = 0 To UBound(vTestItems)
    inList = False
    'check if item is in your dropdown list already
    For j = 0 To UserForm1.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
        If vTestItems(i) = UserForm1.ComboBox1.List(j) Then
            inList = True
        End If
    Next j
    'insert into list if not found
    If inList = False Then
        UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem vTestItems(i)
    End If
Next i

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't realise I needed to loop through all options in the dropdown - I guess that makes sense in hindsight - The code seems legit - I can follow whats happening with it. *pressed Enter for line break - Doh!*

I have attempted the code, but I get:
    "Run-time error ' 13':
    Type Mismatch"
Highlighted at:
For j = 0 To UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.ListCount

Comment: That's probably because .ListCount returns a long and i/j is an integer. You might want to declare i/j as Long / see if you can find a better way to get the total number of items in a listbox or alternatively use `cInt()` to convert the expression to an integer

Comment: I have just attempted to do the same but with:
`Dim m as int`
`m = UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.ListCount`
This also gives type Mismatch?
Putting in `MsgBox UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.ListCount`
This display the list count in a msgbox - But then for some reason throws Type Mismatch AFTER I ok the MsgBox - this is really baffling me, it seems like it should be a fairly simple endeavor

Comment: And what if you declare m, i & j as Long?

Comment: Still gives mismatch?? :/
where would I insert the Cint tag? I attempted `for j = 0 to CInt(UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.ListCount)` - Which still throws mismatch error - Am I doing something really wrong here?

Comment: FYI - full Module atm:

`Public Function DropDown_Init()

Dim Templates() As String
Templates = Split("SmartCard - Termination*Citrix - Frozen Session", "*")

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim inList As Boolean


For i = 0 To UBound(Templates)
    inList = False
    For j = 0 To UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.ListCount
        If Templates(i) = UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.ListIndex(j) Then
            inList = True
        End If
    Next j
    If inList = False Then
        UserForm1.DrpDwn_Templates.AddItem Templates(i)
    End If
Next i

End Function`

Comment: Hi @matthewwalker. I've updated my post to include working example. You may have bit of code in different places but I've brought all of this together to hopefully give you the best picture of what's going on. How does this work?

Comment: I have added the code - Works fine with the looping and running etc - no errors. Only issue is that I have a Button that I use to "Clear" my form - which simply calls the `UserForm1_initialize` which in turn calls the `DrpDwn_Init` function (to run the loops and tests again) and unfortunately starts adding duplicate Items to the list - I'm starting to think at this point, it may be simpler and more efficient to simply clear all items and re-add them all again. *sigh* Which I realize kind of makes all this moot :( - Thanks for your help though! Spot on otherwise ;)

Comment: No problem. It is so quick to repopulate that I'd suggest that as well. Also as you asked the question below - initialising your arrays as Variants shouldn't materially slow down your code but when writing much larger programs it's something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and I got it to work. Doesnt fit your variant needs but gets you closer to figuring it out

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ComboBox1.Clear
    StuffArray(0) = "Stuff"
    StuffArray(1) = "Another thing"
    For i = LBound(StuffArray, 1) To UBound(StuffArray, 1)
        With ComboBox1
            .AddItem StuffArray(i)
        End With
    Next i

    Dim Thing As String
    Thing = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("u9").Value
    For i = LBound(StuffArray, 1) To UBound(StuffArray, 1)
        If Thing <> StuffArray(i) Then
            With ComboBox1
                .AddItem Thing
            End With
        ElseIf Thing = StuffArray(i) Then
        End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Edit- turns out it adds the value twice but thats an easy fix :P

[image]

Comment: Forgive me - I had used the
`Dim Templates() as string`
`Templates = Split("Stuff * andStuff"," * ")`
As i was under the impression that this DIDN'T use the variant data type - Correct me if I'm wrong, but variant uses more memory than strictly necessary right? Hence my using the split method.

Comment: Correct. I also didnt read CallumDA33's answer before I posted(becuase he posted while i was in the middle of typing mine up). I didnt try it out but probably works INF better than mine. I figured I spent a couple of minutes on it Im posting it anyway LOL